# Movie where a man is decapitated by a helicopter

Tags: story-identification, movie

A long time ago I saw a scene from a movie where a man (a high-ranked military, IIRC) standing near a landed helicopter is decapitated by the main rotor blade. Unfortunately this was the only scene I saw, and I always thought that the movie was the third installment of *The Omen* series, but I recently realized that I was wrong (I saw the movie and keep waiting for the scene, with no success). Can anyone provide a reference?

Note: I am not asking about  "Twilight Zone: The Movie", which is known by the death of the protagonist, Vic Morrow, *during filming*. The scene I am talking about is part of the movie plot.

Comment: The title somehow reminded me of the first Indiana Jones movie, where a tough looking nazi guy, who was giving the protagonist a beating, was killed by a plane rotor blade (not a helicopter).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is *Holocaust 2000* which has similar themes to *The Omen*.

Here's a youtube clip:

[Helicopter Clip From Holocaust 2000](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aRLdO_2wD4E)

Answer (score 3):

A zombie in 1978's **Dawn of the Dead** got the top of its head [chopped off by a helicopter](http://www.chillertv.com/friday13/13-amazing-zombie-death-scenes). It somewhat matches your original guess as it's the *second* movie in a series, and the *third movie* is very **military**-centric and prominently features a helicopter. Since they both have helicopters it would be an easy mix-up as for what part of a series.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I barely remember the military saluting some people (or soldiers), with his back turned to the chopper.